# Remove AS3 class itself

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have as3 class like this

```
package  {

import Global;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
public class Alert extends MovieClip {

    public function Alert(alertTitle:String, alertText:String, alertButton:String = "OK") {
        alert_title.text = alertTitle;
        alert_text.text = alertText;
        alert_button.button_text.text = alertButton;            
        this.x = Global.stage.stageWidth/2;
        this.y = Global.stage.stageHeight/2;
        Global.stage.addChild(this);
        alert_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Close);
    }

    public function Close(e:MouseEvent){
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        alert_button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Close);
    }

}

}
```

I use function Close() to remove class itself but i noticed it doesn't frees memory. Is there any way to remove it completely and free used memory?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's memory managed, so the objects won't get freed immediately. After the Garbage collector runs, if nothing is referencing Alert then it will be freed.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player uses Garbage Collection for deallocating memory used by objects.

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html

Generally, removing an object will not immediately be reflected when inspecting memory.  Flash Player runtime will determine the appropriate time to perform the deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

you are also missing.

```
public function Close(e:MouseEvent){
  this.parent.removeChild(this);
  alert_button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Close);
  alert_button=null;
}
```

It might not help the instant memory reallocation that you are looking for but it will allow the GC engine to find it faster.

Also another thought here
This Alert class you have is extremely small and unless you have a few 100 of them on stage you probably won't notice a drastic change in memory at all

Answer (score 0):

If You extends MovieClip , You should for tests add some big bitmapData inside , when GC remove object You will for sure see few or more kb change .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that nothing is linking to this class after you click the close

As far as garbage collection goes, you can use System.gc() for the debug player or for AIR app, here is the documentation for it
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29

You could also use this code to force garbage collection

```
try {
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
    new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:*) {}
// the GC will perform a full mark/sweep on the second call.
```

here is more info about it http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html